# Locations for different program elements

Tags: c++

- Local variables are located on the stack
- Dynamically-allocated memory is located on the heap
- String literals have a const location
- Uninitialized global and static variable are located at .bss (block started by symbol)
- Initialized static and global variables are located in the data section

Where are pointer variables and functions located?

Comment: Until you specify a particular platform, none of what you said is meaningful.  ALL of this is implementation-specific.  The C++ standard doesn't mention stacks, heaps, or sections.

Comment: please take any implementation which supports these i.e. heaps,stacks etc

Comment: The standard does mention dynamic storage duration (aka heap), so not ALL of this is implementation specific.

Comment: @Employed Russian: A heap is not the only possible implementation for dynamic allocations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions are in `.text` section.

Pointers are wherever: local pointers on stack, global/static points in `.bss`, etc.

Yes, an automatic (on stack) pointer could point anywhere (or nowhere at all):

```
void foo() {
   char *p = NULL;               // this pointer points nowhere
   const char *q = "hello";      // points to read-only constant
   char buf[1], *r = buf;        // r points to stack
}
```

There is *no* difference between pointers and other kinds of variables; just as `buf` above ends when `foo()` returns, so do `p`, `q` and `r`.

Also note that that lifetime of the pointer, and the lifetime of the entity it points at have nothing to do with each other. A pointer may have shorter, same, or longer lifetime than the pointed-at entity (and this is a rich source of bugs in `C` and `C++`). Some examples:

```
int *gp1, *gp2, *gp3;
void foo() {
  int j;
  int *lp1, *lp2, *lp3;

  gp1 = lp1 = &j;      // both global 'gp1' and local 'lp1' point to local 'j'
  gp2 = lp2 = new int; // 'gp2' and 'lp2' point to dynamically allocated
                       // anonymous 'int'
  if (true) {
    int j2;
    gp3 = lp3 = &j2;
  }
  // 'gp3' and 'lp3' are "dangling" -- point to 'j2' which no longer exists.
}
```

Once `foo` returns, `gp1`, `gp2` and `gp3` all still exist, but only `gp2` points to valid memory.

Comment: :Can pointer of one location point to data of other section .e.g. :can local pointer can point to global data and vice versa.Also please reply to the second part of my question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply .Can you please tell me one thing also that what is the scope of pointer that is created dynamically i.e. using new .Because I have seen that we can use new in one function and can free it using delete in another function,please reply

Answer (score 1):

Pointer variables have not different to data variables. And functions are your real program, function name will be converted to an internal symbol after compiled used to locate an address in memory where the function body begins and function body will be compiled to assembles, machine code eventually.

=================================================================================

[Edit for the Second Question]

As I pointed out, pointer variables have no different to data variables, including the storage and lifetime. e.g. This is an example .cpp file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int I_m_data = 10;

int *I_m_global;
int *I_m_initialized = &I_m_data;

int main(){
    int *I_m_local = NULL;

    int **dynamic_allocated = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *));

    free(dynamic_allocated);
}
```

Here, `I_m_global` is in .bss section, `I_m_initialized` is in .data section, `I_m_local` is on stack, and pointer pointed by `dynamic_allocated` is on heap while `dynamic_allocated` itself is on stack.

Besides, `I_m_global` and `I_m_initialized` have global lifetime; `I_m_local` and `dynamic_allocated` cannot be indexed out of `main`. Remember free heap space pointed by `dynamic_allocated` manually in case of memory leak.

Good luck!